# YouTube Cards API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am wondering if anybody has any information or news regarding the API (if it exists yet?) of the new YouTube Cards (replacing the old annotations).

Is there any beta api information out yet?

I'm referring to this: [image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 11):

You can track the [YouTube Developer Blog](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com) and also subscribe to the [revision history of YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history), in order to get the latest info on the API, as soon as it is available. Currently (as of the last version of the API - April 27, 2015) there is no way to manage Cards, and I suspect that there would not be, at least not anytime soon.

I think so because currently even annotations are not *fully* supported by YouTube Data API v3 (they only added support for setting *invideo* annotations in v3). I suppose there is a specific reason that this feature has been missing for so long- maybe they don't want to unleash it because they foresee some problems that may arise if they do. It has been requested numerous times in the past by the community (See the last posts in [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=558), where a YouTube representative has answered, also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463242/manage-youtube-annotations-through-youtube-api)).

I'll investigate further to see if I can find any more info on future revisions of the API and will update my answer. Meanwhile, you can submit a [feature request for Card Management API here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)). Good luck!

Comment: if there is no official cards/annotations API, how does tubebuddy work with YouTube?

Comment: @PirateApp - answer is 2 years old currently. It is possible API is available now. Please do add an answer if you confirm this. Or I can update this answer.

Comment: nope i still havent found the API which s why i asked the question about tubebuddy

Comment: It looks like TubeBuddy works through a browser extension rather than using the API – so it probably just injects into the HTML to facilitate card creation client-side.

Comment: any updates on this or how to replicate tubebuddy's results?

Comment: Hey all, any updates on this? Tubebuddy is a browser extension but I checked out its working and they don't really seem to use html to inject or extract information. 
It seems like they use API to get card details but which one is the question.